# jQuery UI tabs in MVC 3 invokes an action on controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a tabs on a page:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Action on the controller of the page looks like:

```
public ActionResult PageWithTabs(int id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Link to the page is:

```
http://localhost:65334/Home/PageWithTabs/1
```

and when I click a tab it goes through link

```
http://localhost:65334/Home/PageWithTabs/1#tabs-2
```

and invokes my action with null id(obviously - 1#tabs-2 not int) and I have an exception.
So, how can I prevent invoking of action on tab clicking?

---

I found out the reason of waking of the action - there is uploadify plug-in on a tab, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // your click logic...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try using @ActionLink instead of a